# The data reader has more than one field. Multiple fields are not valid for EDM primitive or enumeration types from a stored procedure

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I can see this has been asked a few times but can't see one where it relates to a stored proc call like below i can work form.

```
 public ActionResult _NewEmpFifth()
    {

        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> departments = new List<SelectListItem>();
        using (EIPInternalEntities ctx = new EIPInternalEntities())            
        {
            departments = new SelectList(ctx.Database.SqlQuery<string>("EXEC dbo.uspGetDepartments").ToList(), "DepartmentID",  "Department");

            ViewBag.Department = new SelectList(departments, dataValueField:  "DepartmentID", dataTextField:  "Department");        
        }

        var sessionValues = Session["MySessionValues"] as MySessionValues;

        return PartialView();
    }
```

I know the issue is the stored procedure is returning `DepartmentId` and `Department` which is what I want.  Can I bind those to a text a value property under this method?

I'm still new to frame work and MVC.

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: Please add the definition of the SP. Does it return more than 1 column?

Comment: Notice that your question is about EF and has nothing to do with MVC. And "thank you" etc are routinely removed here.

Comment: yes I mentioned in the post it is returning DepartmentId and Department...

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.  Issue was with the  and needed to be replaced by a model that matched the return from the stored procedure.

New model

```
public class GetDepartment
{
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }

}
```

changed controller action

```
public ActionResult _NewEmpFifth()
{

    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> departments = new List<SelectListItem>();
    using (EIPInternalEntities ctx = new EIPInternalEntities())           
    {                              

        ViewBag.Department = new SelectList(ctx.Database.SqlQuery<GetDepartment>("EXEC dbo.uspGetDepartments").ToList(), "DepartmentID", "Department");        
    }

    var sessionValues = Session["MySessionValues"] as MySessionValues;

    return PartialView();
}
```