# How to get records by passing multiple column names dynamically in Asp.net MVC5

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Want to get records from db by passing table name and multiple column names using entity framework

i have tried so far ...

```
 public List<string> GetRecords(List<string> Columns,string tablename)
    {
        using (var Context = new MCPEntities())
        {
             string columnnames = string.Join(",", Columns);
            var Records = Context.Database.SqlQuery<string>("SELECT " + columnnames + " FROM " + tablename + " ").ToList();
            return Records.ToList();
        }
    }
```

The error I get its

> The data reader has more than one field. Multiple fields are not valid for EDM primitive or enumeration types

Comment: Whats the actual problem? Don't keep us in suspense

Comment: Getting this errorr...
"The data reader has more than one field. Multiple fields are not valid for EDM primitive or enumeration types."

Comment: OK. I will _add it to the question for you_

Comment: So if I saw an error like this, the first thing I would do is take a step back and only select one field and see if the error went away. Then I would do some research on the error message

Comment: Basically you need a model to load the data into if you have more than one field. A model is a class that looks like the fields you are returning. Your `Records` would be set to this type. I don't know how you would create this model dynamically. Normally that is a 'presentation' issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29769293/the-data-reader-has-more-than-one-field-multiple-fields-are-not-valid-for-edm-p

Answer (score 1):

**Try**

```
var res = dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<TestEntity>("Select * from dbo.MyView").ToList();
```

with this and try again...

```
var res = dbContext.Database.SqlQuery("Select * from dbo.MyView").ToList<TestEntity>();
```

and if still that is not working then you need to check for your

TestEntity
and your

dbo.MyView
for same columns. because if there is different columns in MyView and TestEntity then it will not work...

If you change the column name in query, then it will throw an exception or it'll not work properly...

if this'll help you then don't forget to mark...

Comment: Yes - in this case `TestEntity` needs to be a class with the same fields as whatever you are returning

Answer (score 0):

By the you have given it should work, what error you are getting.

As my suggestion, first put the query in the separate variable and then check with the breakpoint in Visual Studio, that whether the query has correctly formed or not and then you pass that query to execute. It will surely work.

Example:

```
public List<string> GetRecords(List<string> Columns,string tablename)
{
    using (var Context = new MCPEntities())
    {
         string columnnames = string.Join(",", Columns);

        //check the below line in breakpoint to see the query formation
        string formedquery = "SELECT " +   columnnames + " FROM " + tablename + ""

     var Records = Context.Database.SqlQuery<string>(formedquery).ToList();
        return Records.ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Getting this error...
The data reader has more than one field. Multiple fields are not valid for EDM primitive or enumeration types.